# "unionfs"-like to merge filesystems by date instead of priority

Tags: linux, filesystems

Do you know if there is something similar to unionfs that merges using file timestamps instead of device priority?

e.g.

having two "devices" with these files:

```
/harddisk1/file1.txt (timestamped 11:30)
/harddisk1/file2.txt (timestamped 11:32)
/harddisk1/file3.txt (timestamped 11:33)

/harddisk2/file1.txt (timestamped 11:31)
/harddisk2/file2.txt (timestamped 11:30)
/harddisk2/file3.txt (timestamped 11:33)
```

It should show:

```
/union/file1.txt (timestamped 11:31) [from harddisk2]
/union/file2.txt (timestamped 11:32) [from harddisk1]
/union/file3.txt (timestamped 11:33) [from either harddisk1 or harddisk2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe aufs can do this for you. It's also stackable.